# Alter Column (Syntax Error) SQLite3

Tags: sqlite3

Quiero cambiar los valores de la columna "PASS" que pertenece a la tabla "TRADES" solo si los valores de la columna "ID" de las tablas "TRADES e "INPUTS" son iguales.

Estoy usando el siguiente query pero obtengo un error de syntaxis.

```
"ALTER TABLE TRADES ALTER COLUMN PASS"
"d1.pass as d2.pass"
"FROM TRADES d1"
"FROM INPUTS d2"
"WHERE d1.id=d2.id;"
```

El error que obtengo es:

**near "ALTER": syntax error.**

¿Cómo sería la sintaxis correta para lograr hacer esto?
Muchas gracias!!

---

Pongo un ejemplo de como son las las tablas y lo que quiero hacer:

TABLAS DE ORIGEN:

```
 INPUT            DEALS
ID PASS          ID  PASS
A   1            C   -1
A   1            A   -1
A   1            B   -1
B   2            D   -1
B   2            A   -1
C   3            C   -1
D   4            A   -1
```

RESULTADO BUSCADO DESPUÉS DE LA OPERACIÓN:

```
           DEALS
          ID  PASS
           C    3
           A    1
           B    2
           D    4
           A    1
           C    3
           A    1
```

Comment: `ALTER TABLE` sirve para modificar/añadir/eliminar columnas de una tabla. No sirve para modificar el valor de un campo. De tu query tampoco queda claro qué valor le quieres dar al campo  `PASS` cuando coinciden los identificadores. Intenta dar mas detalles para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Hola!! Gracias por contestar!! Quiero darle el mismo valor que tiene la columna PASS de la tabla INPUTS. Pensaba que se podia hacer asi **"d1.pass as d2.pass"**... lo que intento hacer es moficar todos los valores de esa columna si se cumple la condicion **d1.id=d2.id**

Comment: Acabo de añadir un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer, es muy visual, creo que asi se entenderá mucho mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Esto me ha funcionado:

```
          "UPDATE TRADES "
          "SET pass = d2.pass "
          "FROM INPUTS d2 "
          "WHERE trades.id=d2.id;"
```

Aquí lo dejo por si le es útil a alguien mas.
Gracias y Saludos!!